# Отключить событие на маленьком экране

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите как отключить выполнение события при уменьшении экрана? События mouseover и mouseleave

Comment: `target.removeEventListener(type, listener[, useCapture])`     https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Answer (score 1):

Используйте свойство `screen.width`:

```
if (screen.width > 320) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Нужно в обработчике события `resize` для `window` сравнивать текущую ширину (или высоту, или и то, и другое) с минимальными допустимыми значениями для активации обработчиков событий `mouseover` и `mouseleave`.
Если ширина меньше нужной и обработчики есть, то убираем обработчики.
Если ширина больше нужной и обработчиков нет, то добавляем обработчики.

Пример кода для демонстрации идеи:

```js
var minWidth = 200;
var active = false;
var $block = $('#block');

function onResize() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width > minWidth && !active) {
        $block.on("mouseover", function() {
            $block.css("background-color", "green");
        });
        $block.on("mouseleave", function() {
            $block.css("background-color", "white");
        });
        active = true;
    }
    else if (width < minWidth && active) {
     $block.off("mouseover mouseleave");
        active = false;
    }
}

$(window).on("resize", onResize);

onResize();
```

```css
div {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="block">block</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, но еще вчера разобрался)
Возьму Ваш вариант на заметку))